# WPF Text Rendering issue - Letters are rendered as squares

Tags: .net, wpf, text, rendering

English text is getting displayed as squares.

On one of our users boxes, we are getting this weird behavior. He is on Windows 7 64 bit + decent Video Card. And he started to have that problem quite recently.

I have checked Language settings on the box and it seems to be fine

See the screenshot below, never seen this before. It is not only our WPF forms, it is any WPF form (below is simple window with Label/Text and Button in English).

[image: See the screenshot]

Comment: This usually happens when a font or characters are missing. See Bahri's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the font you are using is installed in Windows/Fonts.

Comment: that's the thing, it is using the default WPF font (which is Segoe UI, I am not overriding it). Found out about that default font when you use Snoop on your app. And that font is already there

Comment: Try copying the file from a system that you know works.  Perhaps it has become corrupted.

Comment: Since you say he has started to have this problem recently (I assume it has worked before on this machine), there is also the possibility that the OS has become corrupted, perhaps because of a faulty disk.  If copying the file from another computer doesn't work, it might be time for a reinstall (I know, that is drastic, but sometimes necessary).  Is this the only symptom of odd behavior on this system?

Comment: yeah, apparently this is the only symptom (other WinForms seems to be running fine). He has been away for 3 weeks and when he came back he started to have problems (it was fine before). will find out more and update. Tnx Bahri

Comment: his fonts were corrupted, trying to get the restored. tnx Bahri

Answer (score 1):

In our case it was a missing font.  We grabbed the fonts from a machine where the wpf app worked and copied them over.  Voila...problem solved

Cheers.